# the website is displaying differently on Safari Mobile View

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Im practicing how to create a responsive website using bootstrap. Everything was fine when i tested my site on Firefox and Chrome using the Resizer extension but when i tried to view it on Safari theres a very small but obvious discrepancy with the bottom padding in one of the boxes(the purple one with the greater than sign). Ill attached the pictures to show what i mean.

Firefox view using Resizer Extension
http://i168.photobucket.com/albums/u173/carlocarr/ScreenShot2013-11-01at52435PM_zps8da019a9.png

Safari view using Developer tools
http://i168.photobucket.com/albums/u173/carlocarr/ScreenShot2013-11-01at52455PM_zps587313c1.png

Is there any Safari Mobile specific CSS?? what should i do? help!

Answer (score 0):

i heard stories that w3cSchool isn't the best resource (due to inaccuracies) but i feel this may be of some use to you. it seems that the image is being cropped but take a look at this and see your own CSS3 code to identify the issues, you may also have to consider using  relative positioning as opposed to absolute.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

also, take into consideration that while some browsers may seem to "now" support the features of CSS3, you need to also check for to version compatibilities. You can set up your site to use specific CSS3 features depending on the versions.

Comment: im not using any css3 nor set it to absolute positioning for that element.